# Is it good to use Semaphore in tasklet execution ISR resource usage

Tags: c, linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I want to use Semaphore in a one of the Bottom half technique in Tasklet timer interrupts, but i know from theory that tasklet won't sleep but semaphore do sleep. any solution for this ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a semaphore instead of a spinlock?

Comment: I Just wanted to know by own interest, i know i can use Spinlock meachanism but i wanted know how to use semaphores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of bottom halves is to perform any interrupt-related work not performed by the interrupt handler itself you want the interrupt handler to perform as little work (and in turn be as fast) as possible and return ASAP to the interrupted code / process.

**Tasklets** are a bottom-half mechanism built on top of softirqs. **Work queue** is another interface for creating kernel threads to handle work that is queued later on. If it must sleep, use work queues. Otherwise, use tasklets.

Spinlocks are always a better choice in dealing with synchronization mechanisms in bottom halves, specially in cases where you are using softirq's or tasklets.

Semaphores: (are only in older 2.6.16 kernels), as mutex's appread after that kernel version. Its recommended to use mutex's when serializing code in the process context.

Comment: Agreed with @askb. Softirq and tasklets run under interrupt context, sleeping is not allowed in  interrupt context. While workqueues run under process context. You can sleep inside workqueues.